# Does LLVM allow multiple instructions in one?

Tags: clang, llvm

I was used to the idea that LLVM resembles assembly language in that instructions are written out in order, one per line, i.e. not like high-level languages that allow subexpressions to be nested, specifying an arbitrary amount of computation in a single line.

Then I noticed that Clang compiles this line of C

```
printf("test\n");
```

into this line of LLVM assembly

```
%6 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([6 x i8], [6 x i8]* @"??_C@_05FPMBMOMC@test?6?$AA@", i64 0, i64 0))
```

What confuses me about this is that the `getelementptr` is written as a *subexpression* of the `call`. I would have expected it to be a separate instruction on the preceding line.

I cannot find anything in the documentation of either of those instructions, or in general, mentioning this being allowed.

What is the rule here? Are subexpressions allowed in general? Or is `getelementptr` an exception? Are there rules governing when `getelementptr` can be a subexpression?

Comment: There is both a GEP constant expression (that takes constant arguments) and an instruction (that can also take variables). The one you saw is a constant.

Comment: @arnt Ah, cool. Can other operators also be used as constant expressions (if given only constant arguments), or is GEP unique in that regard?

Comment: And I found a discussion that sheds some light on the reasoning behind constant expressions: https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2017-March/111247.html

Comment: Much else can be done, see the ConstantExpr class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This an example of so-called "constant expression" and it's not an instruction. More information could be found in LLVM IR Language Reference: https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#constant-expressions